# Output from matplotlib in Juptyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have functioning code in Juptyer notebook to simulate a game of snakes and ladders (chutes and ladders in some places).  The code produces additional out that I have no idea where it is coming from our what parts of it mean.  Ideally I'd like to (a) know why its there and (b) supress it.

Next to Out [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o55GB.png): Juptyer is displaying Text(0.5,1.0, 'Simulated Duration of Snakes & Ladders Games Board')

The 'Simulated Duration of Snakes & Ladders Games Board' is the title I've just set.

What does the 0.5,1.0 refer and can I supress the output -- so that just the image is displayed.

I am assuming this is a parameter somewhere I pass to matplotlib or seaborn?

Sorry for such a low level Q.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a semicolon `;` at the end of the last line of your Jupyter cell to suppress the output. So use

```
plt.title("Simulated Duration of Snakes & Ladders Games Board"); # <--- Semicolon
```

The printed line just shows the text (figure title) that you passed to the `plt.title` and the numbers `0.5, 1.0` tell the location of the title, which is 0.5 (centered) on the x-axis and 1 on the y-axis in relative (or fractional) coordinates.

Comment: Utter genius --> the simplest of solution, but it's been bugging me silly for days now.  Thank you for the solution and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluated value of the last statement in a notebook cell will display in the output area.

For instance, a last statement `abs(-7)` will show a corresponding 7 in cell output.

You can suppress displayed values by appending a no-op like `pass` or `...` after the last statement in a cell.

```py
abs(-7)
pass
```

Alternately, assign to a dummy variable, like

```py
__ = abs(-7)
```

`